# Firebase push notification audiences

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

I have a iOS and a Android app to which I can send push notifications to from the firebase console. I created an audience in the analytics section. Now if I create a push message I think I should be able to select that audience in the target section of the push message. But of course I can't, i only see the two default audiences "Purchasers" and "All Users". 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like audiences that use age, gender or interests to define them are not allowed to be used to target push messages. It is written as a note on the audience creation page in small print.

> Audiences that use Age, Gender or Interest-based filters are not available for targeting in Firebase Notifications and Firebase Remote Config.

Comment: Why is that not allowed, Is it a privacy policy thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Completely agreed with Frank, that you can create up to 50 audiences per project and 
Audiences that include Age, Gender, or Interest data are not available for Firebase targeting may be cause of privacy policies.

In another hand, you can create a custom audience to see the in the Firebase console based on device data, custom events, or user properties to see the reach as per the condition.

Also, you can create Card Abandons, Non-Purchasers audiences..